# What the win cmd to open a particular spreadsheet in Excel?

Tags: windows, excel, vbscript, cmd

I know that you can open an Excel file from the win cmd line.  But how would you open a particular spreadsheet in that file using win cmd?

Comment: hope it helps http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Morpheus.  but this doesn't show me how to get to a particular sheet.  For example, I want to get Sheet2 first, instead of Sheet1.

Comment: I tried a bunch of commands to bruteforce it, nothin seems to be working.

Comment: There's no command-line option for that.  If you really need to do this, create a vbscript which opens the Excel file and activates the required sheet. You can call that from the command line.

Comment: @TimWilliams I really like the way you approach answering questions, you never leap in too early where there is any ambiguity. But in this case I suggest you should have posted the comment above as an answer.

Comment: @brettdj - Thanks.  I try not to post answers unless I'm prepared to go to the trouble of including code...

Comment: @TimWilliams ok, I will jump in then and add this. While I would have recommended the same method for mine you should have taken the credit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Paste the following code into a text editor (NotePad, WordPad, Word 
   etc)
2. Save the file with a "vbs" extension, for example
   `ExcelSheet2.vbs`
3. Change this line `strFileName = "c:\temp\testa.xlsx"` to your
   desired Excel file path
4. You can then run this from the commandline by entering the path name of your vbs file

The code has error handling in case the filepath is wrong, or a second sheet isn't present.

*[**Updated:** added further error handling to test for the second sheet being hidden]*

[image: sample]

```
Const xlVisible = -1
Dim objExcel
Dim objWb
Dim objws
Dim strFileName
strFileName = "c:\temp\test.xlsx"
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
Set objws = objWb.Sheets(2)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not IsEmpty(objws) Then
    If objws.Visible = xlVisible Then
        objExcel.Goto objws.Range("a1")
    Else
        wscript.echo "the 2nd sheet is present but is hidden"
    End If
    objExcel.Visible = True
Else
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    If IsEmpty(objWb) Then
        wscript.echo strFileName & " not found"
    Else
        wscript.echo "sheet2 not found"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Thanks @brettdj, this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could open the workbook from the command line and add the below code to the Workbook to activate "Sheet2"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

End Sub
```

You will need to make sure the workbook is in a trusted location and security settings allow the macro to run.  @brettdj's solution is much superior but this is an alternative.