# editing .vbs to accept a parameter

Tags: vbscript

What I am trying to do is to open an Excel file on a certain worksheet, from a PDF generated by LaTeX, by including `\href{run:./xx.xls}`.

I found the VBScript code below (by @brettdj) very helpful to open a .vbs file with a specified file name.
But how to make the code accept a parameter (to open a different file) each time it is executed, instead of specifying a file name in `strFileName`?

```
Const xlVisible = -1
Dim objExcel
Dim objWb
Dim objws
Dim strFileName
strFileName = "E:RoomContentsAll.xls"
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
Set objws = objWb.Sheets(2)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not IsEmpty(objws) Then
    If objws.Visible = xlVisible Then
        objExcel.Goto objws.Range("a1")
    Else
        wscript.echo "the 2nd sheet is present but is hidden"
    End If
    objExcel.Visible = True
Else
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    If IsEmpty(objWb) Then
        wscript.echo strFileName & " not found"
    Else
        wscript.echo "sheet2 not found"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You set `strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0)` then when executing the script pass the filename as the first command line argument. See http://ss64.com/vb/arguments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WScript.Arguments(0)` is the first parameter, (1) is the second, etc, etc

```
Const xlVisible = -1
Dim objExcel
Dim objWb
Dim objws
Dim strFileName
strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0)
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
Set objws = objWb.Sheets(2)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not IsEmpty(objws) Then
    If objws.Visible = xlVisible Then
        objExcel.Goto objws.Range("a1")
    Else
        wscript.echo "the 2nd sheet is present but is hidden"
    End If
    objExcel.Visible = True
Else
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    If IsEmpty(objWb) Then
        wscript.echo strFileName & " not found"
    Else
        wscript.echo "sheet2 not found"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I guess you missed [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460028/editing-vbs-to-accept-a-parameter#comment56664052_34460028) from 6 hours ago.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers
Thank you very much.
I have 2 other inquiries

1- can the location of the file to be opened be relative to where the vbs file is located instead of being absolute; as specifying strFileName = WScript.Arguments(.\subfolder1\0)

2- Can the others (the tab name in "objWb.Sheets" and the cell reference in "objws.Range"), also be specified as parameters 1 and 2.

Comment: @brettdj  in your formula in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854263/what-the-win-cmd-to-open-a-particular-spreadsheet-in-excel


1- can the location of the file to be opened be relative to where the vbs file is located instead of being absolute; as specifying strFileName = WScript.Arguments(.\subfolder1\0)



2- Can the others (the tab name in "objWb.Sheets" and the cell reference in "objws.Range"), also be specified as parameters 1 and 2.

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you very much.
I have 2 other inquiries

1- can the location of the file to be opened be relative to where the vbs file is located instead of being absolute; as specifying strFileName = WScript.Arguments(.\subfolder1\0), where .\ is the current folder where the vbs file is located, and subfolder1 is the folder where the file-to-open is located

2- Can the others (the tab name in "objWb.Sheets" and the cell reference in "objws.Range"), also be specified as parameters 1 and 2.